# Does the phrase "no sh*t" imply the same meaning as "no kidding"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, offensive-language

Used sarcastically, does "No sh*t, Sherlock." imply the same meaning as "no kidding"?

Comment: Try Google, it has excellent reference. But this has already been answered as well here. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107785/is-there-a-clean-version-of-no-sht-sherlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_shit) which lists "no kidding" as a synonym.